# Ansible how to use looping to run multiple tasks one host at time

Tags: ansible

I have playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: {{ lookup('env','hostname') }}
  tasks:
    - name: Run shell command
      shell: date

    - name: Another shell command
      shell: ls -ltr
```

If I have multiple hosts from  {{ lookup('env','hostname') }} like:

```
host1, host2, host3...
```

how do I run above tasks one host at time using looping over hosts? With above playbook, it runs multiple hosts at same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`serial`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)`: 1`

```
---
- hosts: {{ lookup('env','hostname') }}
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Run shell command
      shell: date

    - name: Another shell command
      shell: ls -ltr
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do using forks option

```
ansible-playbook --forks=1 .. <playbook_name.yml>
```